# Copy data pulled by formulas and then paste it as values within the same sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I put together code to copy data pulled by formulas and then paste it as values within the same sheet. I have multiple workbooks that vary in the amount of worksheets/tabs they contain.

**Problem #1:**
My first worksheet on every file is called REGION.
The code is not executing on the "REGION" worksheet as designed and is also skipping the worksheet immediately after it.

**Problem #2**
Depending on the workbook, after 6 worksheets, I get

> Run-Time Error '1004'

**Problem #3**
On workbooks small enough for the code to cycle through all worksheets and not finding any more worksheets to apply the code I get

> Error 400

**In summary, I need to:**

**1.** Figure out why the code is skipping the worksheet immediately after the one called REGION (1st Tab)

**2.** Prevent error '1004' because the program is performing the same function over and over on multiple worksheets (read that I should probably set it to save every few tabs to prevent this but not sure how to do it while looping).

**3.** Add to the code a line that stops the cycle without throwing an error message.

```vb
Sub COPYPASTE()

Dim ws As Worksheet
    
For Each ws In Sheets
    If ws.Name <> "REGION" Or ws.Name <> "Legend" Then
        Range("C3:I47").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
          :=False, Transpose:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Range("A2").Select
    End If
    ActiveSheet.Next.Select
Next
     
End Sub
```

Comment: you need to fully qualify your ranges, sheets etc. Like ThisWorkbook.Worksheets or Workbooks(2).Worksheets etc. Same for ws.Range("C3:I47").  Copy paste needs to go like this : ws.Range("C3:I47").Copy
ws.Range("C3:I47").Cells(1,1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False

Comment: @cyboashu this should be an Answer not a Comment.

Comment: @JPR please split this out into multiple Questions, StackOverflow rules say that a Question should not present multiple issues, but a discrete single issue.

Comment: @Graham my bad. Because I was in a pinch and posted as fast as I could. I'll make sure to read all rules in detail.

Comment: Consider editing the question so that the accepted answer still makes sense, then move everything else out separately.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Avoid using `Select` and/or `Activate` (and related: `ActiveSheet`, etc.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) and while we're at it, rather than `Copy/PasteSpecial`, just do a direct value-assignment using the range's `Value` property.

So that this:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In Sheets
If ws.Name <> "REGION" Or ws.Name <> "Legend" Then
Range("C3:I47").Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("A2").Select
End If
ActiveSheet.Next.Select
Next
```

Becomes this (also note the `Or` should be an `And`, I think)

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng as Range
For Each ws In Sheets
    'Do not operate on either of Region or Legend worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "REGION" And ws.Name <> "Legend" Then
        Set rng = ws.Range("C3:I47")
        rng.Value = rng.Value2
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This fixed all three issues.

Comment: @DavidZemens, you are correct aboutt the `And` .... the `or` would be `true` for all worksheet names .... ("REGION" <> "Legend)"